# Xcode cpp project: The document "ostream" could not be saved. You don't have permission

Tags: xcode

Что это за проблема и как её решать?

Comment: Вероятно, записывать некий файл туда, где на это есть права.

Comment: ...А еще бывает, что можно так настроить клавиатуру, что нажимаешь "RQ", a печатается "РЯ". Может даже на маке...

Comment: Zdravstvuyte Sergei ! Spasibo za vnimanie ! Konkretiziruyte, ob'yasnite algoritm deystvii. Spasibo za ranee !

Comment: ну, у меня мака нет, точно не скажу. Посмотрел бы, что такое файл "ostream". В коде поискал, в гугле. Куда он пытается записаться, какие там права на запись и владелез папки.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcode/comments/eyzew0/xcode_help_the_document_ostream_could_not_be/

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите ошибку полностью